# Passing Data Frame Columns to Function Error

Tags: r, function

I am writing a function and passing the data frame's columns to function.

You can find the data [here](https://github.com/seckindinc/R)

```
Risk <- read_delim("/home/seckindinc/Desktop/Projects/R/Data/Risk.txt", 
                   "\t", escape_double = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE)

 normallity_plot_func <- function (table_name, column_name) {
   histogram <- hist(table_name$column_name, breaks = 10,  col = "lightgray", xlab = "a")
   xfit <- seq(min(table_name$column_name), max(table_name$column_name), length = 40)
   yfit <- dnorm(xfit, mean = mean(table_name$column_name), sd=sd(table_name$column_name))
   yfit <- yfit * diff(histogram$mids[1:2]) * length(table_name$column_name)
   lines(xfit, yfit, col= "black", lwd= 2)
 }

 normallity_plot_func(Risk,INCOME)
```

> Error in hist.default(table_name$column_name, breaks = 10, col = "lightgray") : 'x' must be numeric

**Note**: Without function this works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call `table_output$column_name` to subset your table. Try:

```
normallity_plot_func <- function (table_name, column_name) {
  histogram <-
    hist(table_name[, column_name],
         breaks = 10,
         col = "lightgray",
         xlab = "a")
  xfit <-
    seq(min(table_name[, column_name]), max(table_name[, column_name]), length = 40)
  yfit <-
    dnorm(xfit,
          mean = mean(table_name[, column_name]),
          sd = sd(table_name[, column_name]))
  yfit <-
    yfit * diff(histogram$mids[1:2]) * length(table_name[, column_name])
  lines(xfit, yfit, col = "black", lwd = 2)
}

normallity_plot_func(iris, "Sepal.Length")
Risk <- read.delim("~/SE/Risk.txt")
normallity_plot_func(Risk,"INCOME")
```

[image]
All i have done is changed `table_output$column_name` to `table_output[,column_name]`

Comment: When i call in your way i get error. normallity_plot_func(Risk,INCOME) Error in check_names_df(j, x) : object 'INCOME' not found

Comment: could you provide more information on your error? Try using base R `Risk <- read.delim("~/yourpath/Risk.txt")` works for me

Comment: When i used your solution R studio turned "not numeric" error. I handled it with this way as.numeric(unlist(